# IOS 8 , adding constraints to the cell.contentview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode6, autolayout

I had two labels in a tableview cell having the dynamic content , so table view cell height depends on the label's height .Adding constraints to the table view cell not working properly after every two cells the label's text truncating.

And i used the following code programmatically done in the custom class

```
NSMutableArray *constraintsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIView *contentView = self.contentView;

[constraintsArray addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:secondLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLastBaseline multiplier:1.0 constant:8.0f]];

[constraintsArray addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1.0 constant:114.0f]];

[constraintsArray addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[firstLabel]-15-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(firstLabel)]];

[constraintsArray addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-15-[secondLabel]-15-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(secondLabel)]];

[self.contentView addConstraints:constraintsArray];
```

Please any help thanks in advance

Comment: Is that all the constraints that you are adding? It would help if you could update your question with maybe a mockup of the layout that you are trying to achieve and expose a bit more code about the layout.

Comment: Actually i need to illustrate using diagram thing is here i don't have enough reputation to attach more images this is the case.Please look this link "https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/", the "What's New in Table and Collection Views" they illustrate using single label but i need with two lables